# Connection to server returns EHOSTUNREACH for all apps after switch from 3g to wifi

Tags: android, tcp, wifi, galaxy

I've built a small android test tcp client that connects to an Ip, sends *hello world*, and periodically sends a datetime.

To test this I am using *netcat* as a server, in the following manner:

```
nc -l 5000
```

The client connects to the server through a socket, and the datetime shows on the *netcat* screen correctly, either using wifi or 3g network.

If start the app in 3g and leave the app sending the datetime on a small period of time (one second interval) and change to wifi network I get **EHOSTUNREACH** for all the connections to my server IP, made by the tcp client app or any other app on any port (for instance the browser) but only in the wifi network where the error occurred.

If I change to 3g or to another wifi network no error is returned, but if I get back to that wifi network I get the error again. And stays that way until I reboot the phone or leave the android alone for about 30 minutes.

This happens in some networks only, and only if the period of data sending is small, 1 second interval or less happens every time I change, if the period is 5 seconds happens 1 in every 4-5 changes.

The client code is the following

```
    private void test(){
    AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            int iterador = 0;
            try {
                if(mSocket!= null && !mSocket.isClosed()){
                    mSocket.close();
                }

                if(waitNetworkConnection(getApplicationContext(), 3))
                {

                    mSocket = new Socket(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
                    mSocket.setReuseAddress(false);
                    mSocket.setSoTimeout(100);
                    mSocket.setTcpNoDelay(false);//false seems to work better
                    mSocket.setKeepAlive(false);
                    mSocket.setSoLinger(false, 5);
                    mSocket.setOOBInline(false);



                    mSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("xxx.xxx.xxx", 5000));



                    PrintWriter out;
                    OutputStream stream = mSocket.getOutputStream();
                    OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(stream);
                    BufferedWriter buff = new BufferedWriter(outputStream);
                    out = new PrintWriter(buff, true);  
                    out.println("hello");
                    out.println("world");

                    Date date;
                    do {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(200);

                            if(out.checkError() || mSocket.isOutputShutdown())
                            {
                                System.out.println("some error has happed let's close the socket");


                                try {
                                    mSocket.shutdownOutput();
                                }
                                catch(Exception e){}
                                try {
                                    mSocket.shutdownInput();
                                }
                                catch(Exception e){}
                                try {
                                    mSocket.close();
                                }
                                catch(Exception e){}

                            }else
                            {
                                if(waitNetworkConnection(getApplicationContext(), 3))
                                {
                                    if(iterador > 10*5)
                                    {
                                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                                    }
                                    date = new Date();
                                    String msg = "["+String.valueOf(iterador)+"] keeping connection at "+date.toString();
                                    System.out.println("Sending: " + msg);
                                    out.println(msg);

                                    out.flush();
                                    iterador++;
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }while(!mSocket.isClosed());

                }
            }
            catch(Exception se){
                String err = se.getMessage();
                if(null == err){
                    err = se.toString();
                }
                System.out.println(err);
            }
            System.out.println("Socket closed");

            new Handler(getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    test();
                }
            }, 5000);

            return null;
        }

    };
    task.execute();
}
public static boolean waitNetworkConnection(Context context, int retries) throws InterruptedException {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo ni = getNetworkToTest(cm);

    if (ni == null || !ni.isConnected()) {
        // sleep a short while to allow system to switch connecting networks.
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < retries && (ni == null || (ni.isAvailable() && 
                !ni.isConnected()))) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            ni = getNetworkToTest(cm);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    return (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && 
            cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected());
}

private static NetworkInfo getNetworkToTest(ConnectivityManager cm) {
    NetworkInfo[] nis = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    for (int i = 0; i < nis.length; i++) {
        if (nis[i].getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI && nis[i].isAvailable()) {
            ni = nis[i];
            return(ni);
        }
    }
    return(ni);
}
```

This tests where made on Samsumg galaxy S3 (android 4.1.2) and Samsung Galaxy S2 (android 4.1.2). 
One network in which this happens the router is an D-link 802.11g/2.4GHz

Comment: Please provide more details about the network and type of upstream provider on which it fails vs those on which it works.  Also, where is the server?  Is it routable (at least sometimes) from all of the test networks?   Do you get different results if you make the interval less frequent?  If you run comparable code on a PC connected to the same network?

Comment: I've used several Ip/servers, and they were all routable and accessible from the test network (confirmed on the test devices before the test occur and after reseting the device). If the interval is less frequent the error may not occur.

Comment: Could you be tripping anti-Denial-of-Service measures in your upstream provider?

Comment: I've used two providers on the same d-link router, and had the same result. Also, this only happens when I am sending data through the app when changing from 3g to wifi. If I restart the android I can use the app on the network that previously failed.